# Use of Spark over Java to connect & fetch data from Oracle

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to retrieve data from Oracle & dump that data to Amazon S3...I want to do it using Apache Spark. I also know that I can do the same using simple Java programming...which one should I choose ? What are the respective advantages of these 2 approaches ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache spark is an overkill for this purpose.

> Apache Spark™ is a fast and general engine for large-scale data processing

Apache Spark is not built for data migration purposes. You can still use it for the purpose but its a overkill.

You can write a bash script or Java program to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script: http://alexbuz.github.io/Oracle_To_S3_Data_Uploader/.
But it for Windows only.